# Importing bootstrap to Vue isn't working

Tags: npm, sass, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm using this guide : http://vuetips.com/bootstrap

on top of the vue-cli scaffolding

and I'm going the sass route.

but beyond the npm install I'm having no luck :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import NavBar from './components/navbar/NavBar.vue'
require('../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss')

Vue.component('NavBar', NavBar)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#NavBar',
  template: '<NavBar/>'
})
```

[image]

i tried editing the path with  an extra `../` in case it was one folder higher but no cigar. I've checked in the pointed folder and the file is indeed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
require('bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss')
```

Webpack already resolves to the node_modules directory.